# Regain focus after non-Java app finishes

Tags: java, macos, desktop

My OS X standalone Java program uses

```
Desktop.getDesktop().open(f);    // Run the Tutorial.pdf file
```

to run the client's default PDF Reader and display a file.  The Reader completes and control is returned to the calling Java program.  But, the Java program does not have the focus.  The client must click it to get focus.  Is there a way for the Java program to regain the focus?  I've tried several things, but all have to do with focus for components of the program - not the program itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To activate your application window use:

```
myFrame.toFront();
```

Be sure to wrap it so that it runs on the EDT, such as `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()`.

If for some reason that doesn't work, you can try:

```
myFrame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
myFrame.setAlwaysOnTop(false);
```

And if that still doesn't work, you can try AppleScript.

```
public class Test extends JFrame {

    public Test() {
        setSize(100, 100);
        setVisible(true);
    }



    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final Timer timer = new Timer();

        final Test test = new Test();

        final TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                test.bringToFront();
            }
        };

        timer.schedule(timerTask, 5000, 5000);
    }



    private void bringToFront() {
        final ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
        final ScriptEngine engine = mgr.getEngineByName("AppleScript");

        try {
            engine.eval("tell me to activate");
        } catch (final ScriptException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, your suggestions were among the several that I tried that didn't work.

Comment: Your AppleScript solution works well - in the general case.  In my specific situation, the Tutorial PDF file is interactive (variable duration) and therefore I could not set the 'bringToFront' timerTask to activate specifically when the Reader app finishes.  Nevertheless, Thank-you for you help.